# Return null if value does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with project data, and I want to return NULL or "Not_Exist" as a result if the `project_ID` was not found.

For example:

```
SELECT a.[Project ID], a.[Stage]
FROM Projects a
WHERE a.[Project ID]  IN ('CR324S', 'a')
```

`CR324S` exists in the table but `'a'` is not there, so the results that I want would be:

```
Project ID     Stage
-----------------------------
CR324S         Implementation
a              Not_Exist
```

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: OUTER JOIN a table/cte having the IN list values.

Comment: What's sql? (mysql, mssql..). Pls add more tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

1. first construct a set of value using union
2. then use left join and put your condition in ON Clause

```
SELECT a.[pid], coalesce(b.[Stage],'Not_Exist') as stage
from
(
    select 'CR324S' as pid 
    union 
    select 'a'
)A left join Projects B on A.pid=B.[Project ID] and [Project ID]  IN ('CR324S','a')
```

OR

```
SELECT a.[pid], coalesce(b.[Stage],'Not_Exist') AS stage
FROM   (VALUES ('CR324S'), ('a')) A(pid)
LEFT JOIN Projects B on A.pid=B.[Project ID] AND [Project ID]  IN ('CR324S','a')
```